# Java standalone consume webservcice

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, webservice-client, webservices-client

I'm new to web service stuff. I need to consume a web service hosted by another application and I have wsdl(development) with me. I need

1. To consume this web service and invoke a specific method
2. Have option to change/set the wsdl link in my program (for QA,UAT and Prod, wsdl points to a different server)

Please suggest the best way to implement this.

Regards,
Manju

Comment: I suppose the best way to implement this is to write code

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html

Answer (score -2):

Ok this is what I did

1. used wsimport tool to generate client. Tried with eclipse to import
   wsdl but gave some errors.
2. By default, the service class had a constructor like

   yourservice service = new yourservice(URL wsdl, QName qname)
3. passed the wsdl( QA,UAT or PROD) using the constructor and it works.

@Lashane, thanks for taking time in answering.

Regards,
Manju